# Text transparent with shadow in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, text, transparency

Example:

[image: Example image]

In the example image is House Gothic Font 3D Shadow and House Gothic font 3d Normal. How can I make it in Photoshop? the same effect like in the example with the font on the top transparent, making possible to see the background image. There is a good tutorial about it? which is technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a version of the font that has the interior of the shapes there are several ways you could do this.

You'll need to have 2 layers with the 3d and non-3d versions of the fonts laid over each other (non-3d above the 3d). Create a duplicate of the background, move it above the regular font in the layers palette and then create a clipping mask of the duplicate background. Now the background will be clipped to the regular text. Link the 2 text layers and you can move the two around while the background stays in place

Another way is to load the non-3d text's selection and apply that as a mask to the 3d text.

In both those cases, you'll have to edit 2 text layers if you need to change the copy.

If that font is this one http://www.houseind.com/t/b9c119 you could also double click the layer and bring up the blending options.

[image: Photoshop's Blending Options]

Grab the black or white slider (depending on the font shadows colour) and pull them into the center until the middle of the text dissapears. Hold down alt/option when you click on the slider and you'll be able to break them in two and get a smooth progression between those two black/white points.